# SQL Too few parameters when using WHERE clause and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, dreamweaver, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to write a query that will display a list of actors who star in at least 1 movie. I'm getting a "Too few parameters. Expected 2." error when I put the WHERE clause in. How do I fix this?

```
<cfquery name="qry1" datasource="torture"> 
    SELECT
        Actors.ActorID,
        Actors.First_Name + ' ' + Actors.Last_Name AS Fullname,
        COUNT( Title ) AS Titles
    FROM
        Actors 
        RIGHT JOIN Videos ON Actors.ActorID = Videos.ActorID
    WHERE
        Fullname <> NULL AND
        Titles > 0
    GROUP BY
        Actors.ActorID,
        Actors.First_name,
        Actors.Last_Name;
</cfquery> 
<cfform name="form" action="Page7Receiver.cfm"> 

    <cfselect name="actor" 
        query="qry1" 
        value="ActorID" 
        display="FullName" 
        required="Yes"
        multiple="No" 
        size="8"> 
    </cfselect> 

    <br><input type="Submit" value="Submit"> 
</cfform>
```

Comment: I don't think using a `RIGHT JOIN` is the best approach here. It's best to right queries in left-to-right order.

Comment: Also, the CF UI components are pretty dreadful IMO. Better to use a plain `<select>` instead of `<cfselect>`. The latter does not buy you much anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by referencing names in your `WHERE` query that don't exist yet (`Fullname` and `Titles`).

Despite that SQL is in `SELECT... FROM... WHERE... GROUP BY... HAVING... ORDER BY...` order, in reality the `SELECT` is evaluated at the end, so your `Fullname` and `Titles` columns are not yet available in your `WHERE` clause.

I suggest reformulating the query like so:

```
SELECT
    Actors.ActorId,
    Actors.First_Name + ' ' + Actors.Last_Name AS FullName,
    COALESCE( VideoInfo.VideoCount, 0 ) AS Titles
FROM
    Actors
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            ActorId,
            COUNT( * ) AS VideoCount
        FROM
            Videos
        GROUP BY
            ActorId
    ) AS VideoInfo ON Actors.ActorId = VideoInfo.ActorId
WHERE
    COALESCE( VideoInfo.VideoCount, 0 ) > 0
    AND
    Actors.First_Name IS NOT NULL
    AND
    Actors.Last_Name IS NOT NULL
```

If we change it to an `INNER JOIN` then we can skip the `Titles > 0` check because the nature of `INNER JOIN` means if an `Actor` has no `Videos` then there won't be a table-join on that `ActorId` anyway.

```
SELECT
    Actors.ActorId,
    Actors.First_Name + ' ' + Actors.Last_Name AS FullName,
    VideoInfo.VideoCount AS Titles
FROM
    Actors
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            ActorId,
            COUNT( * ) AS VideoCount
        FROM
            Videos
        GROUP BY
            ActorId
    ) AS VideoInfo ON Actors.ActorId = VideoInfo.ActorId
WHERE
    Actors.First_Name IS NOT NULL
    AND
    Actors.Last_Name IS NOT NULL
```

Note, the `<> NULL` is not valid SQL. `NULL` is special: you have to use `IS NOT NULL` or `IS NULL` instead.

Comment: *Note, the <> NULL is not valid SQL*  To clarify, the syntax may not throw a syntax error, but .. it will not return any results either.  As Dai mentioned, a `NULL` value is special. It does not equal anything - not even another `NULL`. That is why you must use `.. IS NULL` or `.. IS NOT NULL`.